# Reloading Variable value in NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have finally realised I am going to need to pull in the big 'StackOverflow' guns on this one. Here is my code as this fix continues to elude me

```
var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http');

var ppm = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/ppm.json', 'utf8'));

var timestamp = {"timestamp" : ppm.RTPPMDataMsgV1.timestamp };

var app = express()
    .use(express.bodyParser())
    .use(express.static('public'));

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});

app.get('/ppm/timestamp', function (req, res) {
    res.send(timestamp);
});

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.json(404, {status: 'not found'});
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function () {

    setInterval(function(){
        var ppm = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/ppm.json', 'utf8'));
        var timestamp = {"timestamp" : ppm.RTPPMDataMsgV1.timestamp };
        console.log("File changed");
    }, 30000);

    console.log("Server ready at http://localhost:3000");
});
```

This is a much stripped down version of the final code, but there are a lot more app.get's than just timestamp.

The ppm.json file is being updated every 30 seconds by a separate node program, but the only way I can get this node to use the new file is by stopping and starting the server which is not really acceptable.

I used to do ppm = require('./data/ppm.json) but removed this due to caching and moved to this new method of loading JSON but with no success. I suspect the app is also caching, and therefore.. again.. i would need to restart the server to get the new values

How can I make the value of PPM be reloaded every 30 seconds (or even on a change to the file ppm.json by using fs.watchfile) without reloading the server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the word `var` before `pmm` in your `setInterval` callback. You've made a local `pmm` variable instead of modifying the `pmm` variable in the scope you want to.

You should also avoid the synchronous version of `fs.readFile`, so that your server can respond to requests while the IO is happening.

Comment: All I had to do was drop the VAR... sure I had tried this before, but obviously not. Working lovely now. Very much appreciated